# Fourier-Transformation of $\exp(-|t|)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Using the Fourier-inversion-theorem I have to show that

> $$\frac{\pi}{2}\exp(-|t|)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{1+\omega^2}\mathrm d\omega$$

Can anyone give me a hint on how to show it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Fourier Transform of $\exp(-|t|)$? Additionally, what defintion of the Fourier Transform are you using? Right now your question is missing context and further details and will be most likely closed. Please add these details with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3213255/edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\omega t)d\omega}{1+\omega^2}=\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\cos(\omega t)d\omega}{1+\omega^2}=\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\exp(i\omega t)d\omega}{1+\omega^2},$$where the second $=$ uses the fact that the final integrand's imaginary part is odd. We're trying to evaluate the Fourier transform of $\frac12\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}$, if we define the Fourier transform of $f(\omega)$ as $\int_{\Bbb R}f(\omega)\exp(i\omega t)d\omega$. With this definition, Fourier inversion is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\tilde{f}(t)\exp(-i\omega t)dt$. But$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\pi}{2}\exp(-i\omega t-|t|)dt=\frac14\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(-i\omega t-|t|)dt=\frac12\Re\int_0^\infty\exp(-(i\omega+1)t)dt,$$using$$\int_{-\infty}^0\exp(-i\omega t-|t|)dt=\int_{-\infty}^0\exp(-(i\omega-1)t)dt=\int_0^\infty\exp(-(1-i\omega)u)du=\overline{\int_0^\infty\exp(-(i\omega+1)t)dt}.$$Hence$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\pi}{2}\exp(-i\omega t-|t|)dt=\frac12\Re\frac{1}{1-i\omega}=\frac12\frac{1}{1+\omega^2},$$so we're done.

Comment: Wow! Thank You very much!

Comment: I just worked my way through your answer. Could explain a little more why from the line before "hence" the line after "hence" follows? I just cant get it straight in my head

Comment: @TwoStones It continues from the calculation before "using", viz. $\int_0^\infty\exp(-zt)dt=\frac{1}{z}$ if $\Re z>0$.